# Is there a Stack Exchange site for culture and cultural differences?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

In particular, I would like to ask this question, but I cannot find a Stack Exchange site for it:

**Are Americans indeed reluctant to exercise "position power"?**

I'm reading the book "High Output Management" by Andrew S. Grove, a (naturalized) American, who distinguishes between "knowledge power" - i.e. people who have a lot of influence in a company, not due to formal authority of their position, but due to their knowledge - and "position power", i.e. people who have a formal position of power in the hierarchy of the company.

And here is the statement that I found surprising, and would like to hear other people's opinion whether they share that view:

> We Americans tend to be reluctant to exercise position power deliberately and explicitly -- it is just "not nice" to give orders.

(This is in a context where after discussions in meetings, consensus has not been reached, but for reasons of business a decision needs to be made, and the "position power" person would have to make that decision)

I was surprised to read that the author thinks this is a feature of Americans. Do you think this somewhat sweeping statement is fair? People from what other countries / cultures would be less reluctant to wield position power?

Comment: At a push, maybe  https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/ their help mentions specifically academic philosophy questions are allowed and, with the right wording, you could frame it as a question that fits that criteria. I'm not 100% about it though.

Comment: An anthropology site would be good to see, but it's unlikely to make it through the Area 51 process now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it stands, it looks too broad and too subjective to really be answerable on any site. [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), or to a lesser extent [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), would probably be your best bet, but you'd need to do a lot of work focussing down to the appropriate contexts first.

Comment: Thanks! I decided to put my question here: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/151908/113942

Answer (score 5):

[Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) does welcome questions focused on understanding theories and concepts about interpersonal skills - check out our [academic-research tag](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academic-research) for some examples.

Your question would need a bit of editing first - asking for opinions on whether people agree is definitely, well, opinion-based. However, you might focus on asking if/how this behavior differs across cultures, since that could potentially be answered by other books and research (if that is indeed something you're interested in learning about). If you're unsure, we also have a [sandbox](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3129/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) where you can post a draft of your question and get feedback before posting to the main site!

Answer (score 2):

There are approximately 200 questions pertaining to culture on https://travel.stackexchange.com/:

- https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cultural-awareness
- https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/culture

So sometimes cultural questions are on-topic there.